# Jetpack Compose : How to have nested MutableMap like MutableMap<String MutableMap<String, Boolean>> that trigger recomposition in Composable Function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I want what is written in the title but I didn't managed to...

What I have done :

Declare the nested MutableMap

```
var choicedSourceMaps = remember { mutableStateMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Boolean>>().withDefault { mutableStateMapOf<String, Boolean>().withDefault { false }} }
```

Set wih sample list

```
val sourceList = pair.pairSources.split("|")
choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName] = sourceList.associateWith { false } as MutableMap<String, Boolean>
```

Update in a onclick event

```
choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName]?.put(it.key, true)
```

Value is changed but recomposition is not trigerred

Comment: [+][+][+] : When assigning a new map to it like : `choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName] = mutableMapOf(it.key to true)` - recomposition is triggerred, but we lost the rest of the map..

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this

```
val choicedSourceMaps = remember { mutableStateMapOf<String, Map<String, Boolean>>().withDefault { mapOf<String, Boolean>().withDefault { false }} }
```

And update like this

```
choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName]?.let {
    choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName] = it + mapOf(key, true)
}
```

Comment: It will not edit the actual nested map but rather add data to it. But this is the correct way for nested Map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the answer :

[Nested Collections and Recomposition](https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp)

> State holders like MutableStateFlow, and MutableState only send change notifications when the old and new state values are not equal.
>
> They will not send change notifications if you simply change some
> properties of the object they're holding. They will not send change
> notifications if you mutate the object they're holding, then set that
> same object as the new state. Because the old and new state objects
> are actually the same object, they will always be considered equal
> (this is part of the contract of the equals method in Kotlin and
> Java).

What I have done :

```
var choicedSourceMaps = remember { mutableStateMapOf<String, Map<String, Boolean>>()}

val sourceList = pair.pairSources.split("|")
choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName] = sourceList.associateWith { false }

//copy map
var innerMap = choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName]
//editablemap
var modinnerMap = innerMap?.toMutableMap()
//edit
modinnerMap?.forEach{copiedIt ->
    if(copiedIt.key == it.key){
        modinnerMap?.set(copiedIt.key, true)
    }
    else{
        modinnerMap?.set(copiedIt.key, false)
    }
}
//copy back and trigger recomposition
if (modinnerMap != null) {
    choicedSourceMaps[pair.pairName] = modinnerMap.toMap()
}
```